# Bochner Identity and Integration by parts

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

i'm a little bit confused and frustrated. In this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.0384.pdf on page 10 they use the bochner identity (i omit $\phi$ for sake of convenience)
$$
\Delta \vert \nabla u\vert^2=2\vert \nabla^2 u\vert^2+2\left\langle \nabla \Delta u,\nabla u \right\rangle
$$
to get by integration by parts this integral equation

$$
\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(r^{4-m}\int_{B_{r}^+} \vert D^2 u\vert^2 d x\right)=\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(r^{4-m}\int_{B_r^+} \vert \Delta u\vert^2 dx+2\int_{\partial B_r^+} \left(\dfrac{u_{ii}u_jx^j}{\vert x\vert^{m-3}}- \dfrac{u_ju_{ij}x^i}{\vert x\vert^{m-3}}\right)d \mathcal{H}^{m-1}\right).
$$
When i check this integral equality then the factor 2 does not appear! What i do wrong? Can someone explain with proof why there is also the factor 2?

Thank you.